# Rails + Postgis: error cannot drop table spatial_ref_sys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

Rails 5
Postgresql 9.4.10
Postgis 2.1.8

when I try rake db:reset, console show an error

> ```
> rake aborted! ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
> PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table
> spatial_ref_sys because extension postgis requires it HINT:  You can
> drop extension postgis instead. : DROP TABLE "spatial_ref_sys" CASCADE
> ```

I am new to psql and postgis, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might be referencing the table somewhere

Comment: Do you have any `has_many` relationship(s) setted up with the SpatialRefSys model?

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same issue when I created a migration with `enable_extension :postgis`. This had the intended effect of enabling the extension, but it also updated my `db/schema.rb` file to include this `spatial_ref_sys` table, which is required by postgis.

However, we don't want the `db/schema.rb` file to include this table, because then a `db:drop` or `db:reset` will try and remove the table, and we'll get this error.

To tell rails to ignore this table, we can add the following to the end of `config/environment.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables = ["spatial_ref_sys"]
```

Also, don't forget to remove the `create_table` statement from `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: This should be the right answer imo.

Answer (score 5):

This special table comes with PostGIS extension. It was added automatically. Your schema.rb probably contains line: `create_table "spatial_ref_sys", primary_key: "srid", id: :integer, force: :cascade do |t|`

Then you try to recreate your database with `rake db:reset` or maybe create a test database with `rake`. Because `force` option is set it first drop existing table but it is required by postgis.

The quick solution is to ignore this table in some initializer:

```
::ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables |= %w(spatial_ref_sys)
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` to refresh your schema.rb and it's done.

But more likely you will want to work with some PostGIS features using gem [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter). It will also fix schema.rb for you.